# Form reset button only resetting output without including form input

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, modal-dialog

I am in the process of creating picture framing calculator.  I'm using the W3.CSS modal class to create a popup with calculator.

The problem I'm running into is that my reset button only resets the **output** of the user's interaction when it should also include the form inputs.  Here's the code snippet. Please use the following inputs as an example.

1. Frame Width:  16
2. Frame Height:  20
3. Picture Width:  11
4. Picture Height:  17
5. Mat Overlap:  1

```js
function calc()

{

  var frameWidth = document.getElementById('frameWidth').value
  frameWidth = parseInt(frameWidth)

  var frameWidthFraction = document.getElementById('frameWidthFraction').value
  frameWidthFraction = parseFloat(frameWidthFraction)

  var frameHeight = document.getElementById('frameHeight').value
  frameHeight = parseInt(frameHeight)

  var frameHeightFraction = document.getElementById('frameHeightFraction').value
  frameHeightFraction = parseFloat(frameHeightFraction)

  var pictureWidth = document.getElementById('pictureWidth').value
  pictureWidth = parseInt(pictureWidth)

  var pictureWidthFraction = document.getElementById('pictureWidthFraction').value
  pictureWidthFraction = parseFloat(pictureWidthFraction)

  var pictureHeight = document.getElementById('pictureHeight').value
  pictureHeight = parseInt(pictureHeight)

  var pictureHeightFraction = document.getElementById('pictureHeightFraction').value
  pictureHeightFraction = parseFloat(pictureHeightFraction)

  var matOverlap = document.getElementById('matOverlap').value
  matOverlap = parseInt(matOverlap)

  var matOverlapFraction = document.getElementById('matOverlapFraction').value
  matOverlapFraction = parseFloat(matOverlapFraction)

  if (isNaN(frameWidth) || isNaN(frameHeight) || isNaN(pictureWidth) || isNaN(pictureHeight) || isNaN(matOverlap)) {
    alert('All fields are required!')
    return
  }

  var width = (1 / 2) * ((frameHeight + frameHeightFraction) - (pictureHeight + pictureHeightFraction) + (matOverlap + matOverlapFraction));
  var height = (1 / 2) * ((frameWidth + frameWidthFraction) - (pictureWidth + pictureWidthFraction) + (matOverlap + matOverlapFraction));

  document.getElementById('width').innerHTML = new Fraction(width).toString() + '"';
  document.getElementById('height').innerHTML = new Fraction(height).toString() + '"';

}

function resetOutput() {
  document.getElementById('width').innerHTML = ""
  document.getElementById('height').innerHTML = ""
}
```

```html
<div id="singleMatModal" class="w3-modal">
  <div class="w3-modal-content w3-animate-zoom w3-card-4">
    <header class="w3-container w3-teal w3-center w3-padding-32">
      <span onclick="document.getElementById('singleMatModal').style.display='none'" class="w3-button w3-teal w3-xlarge w3-display-topright">×</span>
      <h2 class="w3-wide"><i class="fa fa-calculator w3-margin-right"></i>Single Mat</h2>
    </header>
    <div class="w3-container">

      <form id="singlematcalculator" action="responsive.ejs" onreset="resetOutput()" method="post"></form>
      <div class="w3-section">

        <label>Frame Width</label>
        <input class="w3-input" style="width:100%;" type="number" title="numbers should be in inches" onkeypress="return (event.charCode == 8 || event.charCode == 0 || event.charCode == 13) ? null : event.charCode >= 48 && event.charCode <= 57" step="any" min="0"
          name="frameWidth" id="frameWidth">
        <span class="inline">
            <select class="w3-input w3-round" style="width:100%;" name="frameWidthFraction" id="frameWidthFraction">
                <option value="0">0</option>
                    <option value="0.0625">1/16</option>
                        <option value="0.0125">1/8</option>
                            <option value="0.1875">3/16</option>
                            <option value="0.25">1/4</option>
                            <option value="0.3125">5/16</option>
                            <option value="0.375">3/8</option>
                            <option value="0.4375">7/16</option>
                            <option value="0.50">1/2</option>
                            <option value="0.5625">9/16</option>
                            <option value="0.625">5/8</option>
                            <option value="0.6875">11/16</option>
                            <option value="0.75">3/4</option>
                            <option value="0.8125">3/16</option>
                            <option value="0.875">7/8</option> 
                            <option value="0.9375">15/16</option>
            </select>
        </span>
      </div>

      <div class="w3-section">
        <label>Frame Height</label>
        <input class="w3-input" style="width:100%;" type="number" title="numbers should be in inches" onkeypress="return (event.charCode == 8 || event.charCode == 0 || event.charCode == 13) ? null : event.charCode >= 48 && event.charCode <= 57" step="any" min="0"
          name="FrameHeight" id="frameHeight">
        <span class="inline">
            <select class="w3-input w3-round" style="width:100%;" name="frameHeightFraction" id="frameHeightFraction">
                <option value="0">0</option>
                    <option value="0.0625">1/16</option>
                        <option value="0.0125">1/8</option>
                            <option value="0.1875">3/16</option>
                            <option value="0.25">1/4</option>
                            <option value="0.3125">5/16</option>
                            <option value="0.375">3/8</option>
                            <option value="0.4375">7/16</option>
                            <option value="0.50">1/2</option>
                            <option value="0.5625">9/16</option>
                            <option value="0.625">5/8</option>
                            <option value="0.6875">11/16</option>
                            <option value="0.75">3/4</option>
                            <option value="0.8125">3/16</option>
                            <option value="0.875">7/8</option> 
                            <option value="0.9375">15/16</option>
            </select>
        </span>
      </div>

      <div class="w3-section">
        <label>Picture Width</label>
        <input class="w3-input" style="width:100%;" type="number" title="numbers should be in inches" onkeypress="return (event.charCode == 8 || event.charCode == 0 || event.charCode == 13) ? null : event.charCode >= 48 && event.charCode <= 57" step="any" min="0"
          name="pictureWidth" id="pictureWidth">
        <span class="inline">
            <select class="w3-input w3-round" style="width:100%;" name="pictureWidthFraction" id="pictureWidthFraction">
                <option value="0">0</option>
                    <option value="0.0625">1/16</option>
                        <option value="0.0125">1/8</option>
                            <option value="0.1875">3/16</option>
                            <option value="0.25">1/4</option>
                            <option value="0.3125">5/16</option>
                            <option value="0.375">3/8</option>
                            <option value="0.4375">7/16</option>
                            <option value="0.50">1/2</option>
                            <option value="0.5625">9/16</option>
                            <option value="0.625">5/8</option>
                            <option value="0.6875">11/16</option>
                            <option value="0.75">3/4</option>
                            <option value="0.8125">3/16</option>
                            <option value="0.875">7/8</option> 
                            <option value="0.9375">15/16</option>
            </select>
        </span>
      </div>

      <div class="w3-section">
        <label>Picture Height</label>
        <input class="w3-input" style="width:100%;" type="number" title="numbers should be in inches" onkeypress="return (event.charCode == 8 || event.charCode == 0 || event.charCode == 13) ? null : event.charCode >= 48 && event.charCode <= 57" step="any" min="0"
          name="pictureHeight" id="pictureHeight">
        <span class="inline">
            <select class="w3-input w3-round" style="width:100%;" name="pictureHeightFraction" id="pictureHeightFraction">
                <option value="0">0</option>
                    <option value="0.0625">1/16</option>
                        <option value="0.0125">1/8</option>
                            <option value="0.1875">3/16</option>
                            <option value="0.25">1/4</option>
                            <option value="0.3125">5/16</option>
                            <option value="0.375">3/8</option>
                            <option value="0.4375">7/16</option>
                            <option value="0.50">1/2</option>
                            <option value="0.5625">9/16</option>
                            <option value="0.625">5/8</option>
                            <option value="0.6875">11/16</option>
                            <option value="0.75">3/4</option>
                            <option value="0.8125">3/16</option>
                            <option value="0.875">7/8</option> 
                            <option value="0.9375">15/16</option>
            </select>
        </span>
      </div>

      <div class="w3-section">
        <label>Mat Overlap</label>
        <input class="w3-input" style="width:100%;" type="number" title="numbers should be in inches" onkeypress="return (event.charCode == 8 || event.charCode == 0 || event.charCode == 13) ? null : event.charCode >= 48 && event.charCode <= 57" step="any" min="0"
          name="matOverlap" id="matOverlap">
        <span class="inline">
            <select class="w3-input w3-round" style="width:100%;" name="matOverlapFraction" id="matOverlapFraction">
                <option value="0">0</option>
                    <option value="0.0625">1/16</option>
                        <option value="0.0125">1/8</option>
                            <option value="0.1875">3/16</option>
                            <option value="0.25">1/4</option>
                            <option value="0.3125">5/16</option>
                            <option value="0.375">3/8</option>
                            <option value="0.4375">7/16</option>
                            <option value="0.50">1/2</option>
                            <option value="0.5625">9/16</option>
                            <option value="0.625">5/8</option>
                            <option value="0.6875">11/16</option>
                            <option value="0.75">3/4</option>
                            <option value="0.8125">3/16</option>
                            <option value="0.875">7/8</option> 
                            <option value="0.9375">15/16</option>
            </select>
        </span>
      </div>

      <button class="w3-button w3-block w3-teal w3-padding-16 w3-section w3-right" onclick="calc()" value="Calculate" name="cmdCalc">CALCULATE<i class="fa fa-check"></i></button>
      <input type="reset" onclick="resetOutput()" class="w3-button w3-block w3-teal w3-padding-16 w3-section w3-right" value="RESET">
      <button class="w3-button w3-red w3-section" onclick="document.getElementById('singleMatModal').style.display='none'">Close <i class="fa fa-remove"></i></button>
      <p class="w3-right">Need <a href="#" class="w3-text-blue">help?</a></p>

      <script src="https://iwasframed.com/calculator/fraction.js/index.js"></script>

      <div class="square-container-single">
        <div class="square-single">

          <div class="content-single">
            <span><div id="width"></div>
                <div class="content-single spread">
              <div id="height"></div>
            </div>
                
                </span>

          </div>
        </div>



      </div>
    </div>

    </form>
```

As you can see from running the snippet - the `output` produced is:

> 2"
>
> 3"

However, the issue is the Reset button.  The button in question:

```
<input type="reset" onclick="resetOutput()" class="w3-button w3-block w3-teal w3-padding-16 w3-section w3-right" value="RESET">

function resetOutput() {
  document.getElementById('width').innerHTML = ""
  document.getElementById('height').innerHTML = ""
}
```

Only Resets the output as I have outlined with `function resetOutput()`.

### WHAT I'VE TRIED

---

I've tried using the most commonplace way to reset a form:  `<input type="reset" value="Reset">`

I also tried adding `document.getElementById("singlematcalculator").reset();` by adding the line to as so:

```
function resetOutput() {
  document.getElementById('width').innerHTML = ""
  document.getElementById('height').innerHTML = ""
  document.getElementById("singlematcalculator").reset();
}
```

All in all, what I'm trying to do is create a reset button which resets both the FORM INPUT and the OUTPUT.  Currently, I can only reset the output

-----EDIT-----

[image: Image of output from code snippet]

I uploaded the project to Heroku at: [Complete source code and project on Heroku](https://iwasframed.herokuapp.com#calculator).  Please navigate from the navbar:  Calculators > Single Mat > "Calculate" button in the Single Mat box.

Comment: `the output produced is: 2" 3"` the output I get from the values you specify is `2" 28"`...? Also, the snippet doesn't contain any reference to w3.css? Not that it appears to matter to the issue as it's to do with the JS updating form values. As an aside, I would generally suggest avoiding any resources/tutorials from W3Schools as they are outdated and very rarely following good practices. Use Bootstrap, Material, even jQueryUI if you want a reliable UI framework.

Comment: Also, upon checking your HTML, the `form` element is immediately closed, so none of the `input` or `select` elements, or even the reset button itself, are actually contained within a form - this is why the `reset` button 'doesn't work' for you.

Comment: For future reference, please see [mcve].  You don't need 10 inputs to demonstrate/test a form reset.

Comment: You would also benefit from separating your events from the "onclick=" into event handlers (js or, as tagged jquery despite none, jquery events).   This makes adding "return false" to your submit handler easier than `onclick="calc();return false;"`.  Also use a decent IDE as it will show your errors - pasting your HTML as-is into jsfiddle highlights the extra `</form>` at the end as noted in comment above.   Removing the first `</form>` and cancelling the submit, your [reset works fine](https://jsfiddle.net/j2w01ahp/)

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan I uploaded the project to [Heroku](https://iwasframed.herokuapp.com#calculator).  So, under the "Calculators" section, there's a box for "Single Mat" with a button called "Calculator."  That modal is the one in question.  Since you can see all the source code - does this help with some questions?  Also, if I shouldn't use use w3.CSS then will I be able to easily convert my current project over to Bootstrap?

Comment: @freedomn-m First off, yes, I went a little crazy there with the demonstration resets.  Secondly, it works now!  I really appreciate it.  I don't have much reputation, but I'd be willing to give you some if I'm able to.

Comment: w3.css isn't related to your issue, it's just w3schools *in general* have had some issues.